# What's the best way to get the next row from a sqlite table everytime my python script runs?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a python script that pulls one image url from a sqlite database and submits it to my blog. Cron runs this script once every hour. Everytime the script runs, it needs to get the next row in the table so it would need to somehow remember the id of the row that was "fetched" the last time the script ran. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is. Right now I'm just saving the id of the last fetched row in a file which my script reads on startup.

Comment: Add a boolean column to the table so you can mark *in the database* that the row has been handled?

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Persisting the last ID fetched seems fine to me, though I would probably persist it to another, dedicated single-record table of the DB, just to avoid having another separate file around.